# What should I do with my frustration at having a question closed after writing a thoughtful answer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, etiquette

On more than one occasion I have attempted to compose a thoughtful and helpful response to a question, only to have it closed underneath me when I try to save my answer.

For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659769/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-book-for-independently-learning-java#10659769

I realize that posting this question here may not be the answer to itself, but I really would like to know how other people handle this situation? Is it just a matter of thinking to myself, "I will not help this person because other people won't like their question" and moving on?

Comment: A number of type of questions are very likely to get closed, quickly. Book requests is one of them. Avoid answering those types of questions.

Comment: Exactly, only not quite like that. See it as "I will not answer this question because it is off topic and will be closed/deleted anyway".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on the tags to see if there are other questions of that variety that also need closing (in this case it's the [books](/questions/tagged/books) tag).  Vote to close or flag a few of them.